# Why does the wikipedia implementation of Stoer-Wagner algorithm (for global min cut) give wrong answer?

Tags: algorithm, max-flow

I was studying Stoer-Wagner algorithm and I found a wikipedia implementation (which is the same as the one Stanford university uses in ACM ICP PDF). It states the cut is not correct but I don't understand why.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoer%E2%80%93Wagner_algorithm
Could you give me a hint? I don't understand the case it proposes...

Comment: The posted Wikipedia code looks *horrible* and looks like it was written with no intent to be readable or maintainable. But without knowing on what input you were running that code or what "it" is that states the cut is not correct, I'm not sure we can help you. Can you provide enough information for us to reproduce this error on our end?

Comment: Wikipedia code, even pseudocode is frequently awful.  I have found many incorrect implementations.  It's very distressing when trying to learn a new or sophisticated algorithm.

Comment: It's hard to tell with undocumented/uncommented code, but this line `for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) weights[j][prev] = weights[prev][j];` looks off: try with an auxiliary destination array.